# Recycler view is not listing and getItem count return 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view with some edit text. but I couldn't list the values in recycler view and it is not showing any errors but recycler view is not showing anything.
I can fetch the data which I need to display from the API but in the adapter class the getItemcount() return 0 size.

**Activity class**

```
class Activity_addstaff : AppCompatActivity() {
internal var sprefs: SharedPreferences? = null
var token: String = ""
private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>? = null
private var Outnameslist: MutableList<Outletnamelist>? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addstaff)
    try {
        sprefs = this!!.getSharedPreferences(
                Config.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        token = sprefs!!.getString("token", "No")!!
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
    try {


        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        outletnameslistrecycle!!.layoutManager = layoutManager
        Outnameslist = ArrayList()
        adapter = outletname_adapter(Outnameslist as ArrayList<Outletnamelist>, this)
        outletnameslistrecycle!!.adapter = adapter
        getoutletlist();
    } catch (e: Exception) {

        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

private fun getoutletlist() {

   Outnameslist!!.clear()

    val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_OUTLET_NAME,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                try {

                    val obj = JSONObject(response)

                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {

                        val userssListArray = obj.getJSONArray("outletlist")
                        for (i in 0 until userssListArray.length()) {
                            var usersObj = userssListArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            var outlet = Outletnamelist()
                            outlet.id=usersObj.getInt("outlet_id")
                            outlet.name=usersObj.getString("outlet_name")
                            System.out.println("valuefrom api"+outlet.name)

                        }

                        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()



                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(this, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        if (obj.getString("message") == "Your login expired please re login") {
                            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }

                    }


                } catch (e: JSONException) {

                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Network Error Try Again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["token"] = token

            return params
        }
    }
    stringRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            15000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)

    VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)

}
```

}

**AdapterClass**

```
class outletname_adapter (internal var Outnamelist: List<Outletnamelist>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<outletname_adapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.lay_outletnamelist, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(v, context, Outnamelist)



    return null!!
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    try {
        System.out.println("testgjo "+Outnamelist[position])
        var OutletList =Outnamelist[position]

        holder.outlet_name!!.text=OutletList.name


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return Outnamelist.size

}

inner class ViewHolder(v: View, var context: Context, private val outnamelist: List<Outletnamelist>) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {

var outlet_checkbox: CheckBox? = null
   var outlet_name: TextView?=null

    var layTop: LinearLayout?= null
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        try {
           outlet_checkbox=v.findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox
            outlet_name=v.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_in)as TextView

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val position = adapterPosition
    }
   }


   }
```

**XML**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/diagonal_bg"
    tools:context=".Activity_addstaff">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/img_staff"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
        android:src="@drawable/subadmin"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/staffname_text_input"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/staffname_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:hint="@string/label_staffname" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/staffaddress_text_input"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/staffaddress_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:hint="@string/label_address" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/staffplace_text_input"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/staffplace_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:hint="@string/label_place" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/staffpin_text_input"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/staffpin_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:hint="@string/label_pin" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/staffmob_text_input"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/staffmob_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:hint="@string/label_mob"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/lay_root"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">


                <LinearLayout

                    android:id="@+id/lay_root2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/outletnameslistrecycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="1dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btneditstaff"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    style="@style/DefaultButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, you have created **outlet** but didn't add into **Outnameslist**.

**Solution-** Add **outlet** into **Outnameslist**

```
var outlet = Outletnamelist()
Outnameslist.add(outlet)
```